# Mechanism to generate RMI automatically from Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: java, rmi, processbuilder

i'm working on a project for my thesis in JAVA which requires automatic RMI generation from Abstract Syntax Tree. I'm using RMI as

```
`public int createProcess(CompilationUnit cu){
   //Some Code Here
 return processid;
   } `
```

for generating RMI from AST on each node. And it will automatically generates the Interface file and all the java files from AST and put all the methods in these files. I am able to execute the `javac`, `rmic <remote-class>`, `rmiRegistry` commands using process builder. But

1. how to destroy and unbind the remote objects after process completion ? Do i have to put this code at the end of each file where control exits ?

   ```
    public void exit() throws RemoteException
     {
     try{
      // Unregister ourself
         Naming.unbind(mServerName);

   // Unexport; this will also remove us from the RMI runtime
       UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);

      }
       catch(Exception e){}

      }
   ```
2. Do i have to execute rmiRegistry after every remote method/classes creation or it will automatically adds the later remote methods/classes to registry, if it is already in the executing state (means if processbuilder is already executing the command "rmiRegistry") ? For example if nodeA creates a Process1 (RMI class) on nodeB and then execute it using commands via Processbuilder, rmiRegistery will be in running state. Now if NodeA wants to create another Process2 on NodeB, do i have to stop that instance of rmiRegistery and rerun it, or there is no need to do that Registery will detect & add new bindings automatically?
3. Will all the RMI run on same port ?? means if i create process1 and bind it with localhost/process1 & process2 with localhost/process2 ,  can we access them via same port ?

i'm working with RMI first time so don't have any previous experience or knowledge.

Apologies, my question seemed unclear , so i tried to put more explanation by editing ?
Following this tutorial [Link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-rmi-client-and-server-to-invoke-remove-method-of-rmi-server-in-java/28320)

Comment: You don't need to invoke rmic. RMI is able to generate its stubs dynamically.

Comment: @StuartMarks Sir i'm using this tutorial http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-rmi-client-and-server-to-invoke-remove-method-of-rmi-server-in-java/28320

Comment: @StuartMarks Sir, does that means i have to compile the files only and then start the rmiRegistry ?

Comment: It is no longer necessary (since Java 5, released 2004) to use `rmic` to generate stubs. They're now generated dynamically. In fact, Java 8, released earlier this year, has deprecated `rmic`. Just compile the remote interface and its implementation, export it, and [UnicastRemoteObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html) will create the stub automatically. The [Oracle RMI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) is more up-to-date than the one you're using.

Comment: The registry is a separate issue from stubs. If you fork an `rmiregistry` process, you need do so only once. But as EJP noted, it might be easier to use [LocateRegistry.createRegistry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html) to create the registry service in the same JVM, avoiding the need to fork a subprocess.

Comment: @StuartMarks i didn't know about the change in RMI, thanks  .. :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1 how to destroy and unbind the remote objects after process completion ?

See 2, but I don't know why you want to do so. Just leave them in existence and bound to the Registry.

> 2 Do I have to put this code at the end of each file where control exits ?

Yes, if you want it to execute, otherwise no. Don't generate empty catch-blocks though.

> 3 Do I have to execute rmiRegistry after every remote object creation

No, you have to start it once, at the beginning of the containing process. Simplest way is via LocateRegustry.createRegistry().

Comment: apologies, i have to edit my question to make it more clear, i think.  BTW `LocateRegustry.createRegistry()` will this bind all the objects to same port. In my thesis i will be running multiple process from other nodes so to make it more manageable & clean i may have to delete the objects, so that if in future same process is created again we can bind it to same registry. Thanks :)

Comment: Re your edit, the Registry doesn't 'detect new bindings automatically'. New bindings are created by a registry.bind()/rebind(). I don't understand your remark above about different ports. You don't need multiple Registries running on different ports per host.

Comment: I am not good at explaining , but let me try, there will be server code and client code generated on each call to create process on both nodes. (Correct ?) . in each client code do i have to call to same port or each registry will bind itself to new port? Also as stuart suggested now i do have to compile the RMI code only. And then execute the `start rmiregistry` or `rmiregistry` depending on OS. But now another problem is if i generate another server client code on both nodes when `rmiregistry` is already execute state or one of code is already running , do i have execute a seprate TBC...

Comment: Cont. instance of `rmiregistry` or kill first one and then re-execute `rmiregistry` or  keep `rmiregistry` alive, it will detect new code execution and will handle it ?? OR as per your suggestion i can add `LocateRegustry.createRegistry()` to one per generated code and when newer code will be executed it will handle all previous bindings also ??

Comment: As I already told you that you don't need multiple Registries running on different ports per host, these question about multiple registries and different ports simply do not make sense. @stuartmarks is correct about the stubs.

Comment: Thanks :) i will put sample code in answers or do i have to accept your answer.

Comment: Do i need webserver installed on each node to run RMI ?

Comment: No, RMI runs with just a JRE.